# How to create a single activity without headers

Tags: android, setting

I'm developing an application where I set up an activity for the settings.
I tried to use the android studio template to create an activity setting but the structure of the code that is being created is too complex.
Can anyone tell me how to create a settingsActivity similar to the android studio template but without headers?
Thanks in advance for the answer.
Greetings.

Comment: What do you mean by headers?

Comment: AndroidStudio creates a settingsActivity with headers such as general, sync and frequency.
I would like a settingActivity that would show me the settings directly without having these headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a single settingActivity you can try the below pseudo code:

```
public class SettingsUI extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings_preference, false);
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preference);
         }
     }
  }
```

Then `settings_preference.xml` code:

```
PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference 
android:key="sample_key" 
android:title="@string/sample_title" 
android:inputType="number"  
android:summary="@string/sample_summary"/>

<EditTextPreference 
android:key="sample2_key" 
android:title="@string/sample2_title" 
android:inputType="number"
android:summary="@string/sample2_summary"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the styles.xml file, please make one style tag if you want to remove actionbar(you said header) in only specific activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

And goto AndroidManifest file, please apply above style to your activity something like this.

```
<activity android:name=".SettingActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme1"></activity>
```

if you want to remove actionbar in all of your activities, then you can change AppTheme style in the styles.xml file like below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mainColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    ... ...
```

Comment: But I do not want to remove the actionBar, but I would like a single settingActivity with the preferenceFragment.